# UDP port forwarding required?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, udp

Sorry because of this dumb question but I didn't quite find an answer. So for TCP only the server needs a port forwarding, but not the client. But since UDP doesn't technically differentiates between client and server, do I have to port forward for the client too? (AFAIK TCP does it itself as soon as it connects to the server)

Comment: I assume your question refers to port forwarding in routers to make internal systems accessable to the outside (if not please add more context to your question). In this case port forwarding must be added for UDP too, because otherwise the initial packet from the UDP client (this is who initiates the connection) will not be seen by the UDP server (this is who receives the initial packet).

Comment: Yes I mean port forwarding in routers. But do I have to do port forwarding on the CLIENT router? (The router in front of the client computer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the client is behind a NAT firewall, then yes, you will need a client port forward.  Many NAT routers support "automatic" UDP forwarding, that automatically sets up a temporary port forwarding whenever it sees an **outgoing** packet (the client is sending data to the server), so that the reply packets can make it back to the client. You may need to configure your router to enable this, and may need to set various timeout parameters to make it work properly (since UDP does not have any timeouts built into the protocol).

Note that this kind of reverse port forwarding is ALSO needed for TCP, but all NAT router/firewalls do that automatically, as they would be useless without it.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I wanted to know.