# Port forwarding when using UDP sockets?

Tags: c#, networking, udp

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206624/udp-port-forwarding-required) I knew that the client needs to forward ports in order for their program to contact with mine, but I am making a game. Should every user froward a port before playing the game? Is there a better solution?

Comment: That depends on how you constructed your game. If you have a server running on one computer that everyone connects to, only the server router would need port forwarding (as outgoing connections aren't usually blocked by the client's router). However if each client must accept connections from other clients, every user needs to port forward.

Comment: Since UDP is connection-less then There is no server or a client ,but I may forward any ports on the server computer. I just don't want the clients to forward ports manually.

Comment: When I said _server_ I was referring to _a server application_ working as a host for all players... And what? You **don't** want them to forward ports automatically? Ports aren't usually forwarder automatically, rather temporarily. --- **EDIT:** Oh you meant manually. Well they usually wouldn't need to if they connect to a server. They would only need to if they connect to each other.

Comment: That was a typo, I edited the comment. I meant manually

Comment: Then if I have port forwarding done on the server computer, the clients won't need to forward any ports @Visual Vincent??

Comment: Not usually, no. As mentioned in the question you linked, some NAT routers would set up a temporary forward for outgoing connections so that it can also receive data, but there are always exceptions (which you can do nothing about anyway).

Comment: Thanks so much! That should be an answer! If you repeat the last comment as an answer I would set it to correct.

Comment: I'd say most. I don't know for certain, but I've never experienced such a problem from anyone.

Comment: No problem. Outgoing connections are usually made by you, so that's why there's automatic temporary forward: if you made the connection, you want to connect to it. Why block it if the user has control of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a server application on one computer acting as host for all players, you usually only require the server's router to be port forwarded.

If the clients would connect to each other, however, each client would require port forwarding.

As mentioned in the question you linked, some NAT routers set up a temporary forward for outgoing packets so that the user may both send and receive data on that specific port. This means that port forwarding is mostly only required when you are to receive incoming connections and data from outside your LAN. So *most* users will be able to connect to your server without a problem. The ones that don't, you can do nothing about.